# Get variations of a color in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, colors

I download a script and in it, it had this code which generates a variation of green. I am not sure I understand it. I would like to modify it to get a desired color with different variations. Can anyone explain this snippet to me?

```
var color:uint = 0 | int(getRandom(80, 256)) << 8 | 0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

There are three different colors in the uint. RGB.

```
var color = RED << 16 | GREEN << 8 | BLUE;
```

That makes up a color in which you can use. To make the example above generate a random yellow color I would just use:

```
var color = int(getRandom(180, 255)) << 16 | int(getRandom(180, 230)) << 8 | 0;
```